# Cannot update laravel/passport

Tags: laravel, api

Actually Im trying to set API for my website on Laravel. I found that I need to add CreateFreshApiToken to Kernel.php in order to use it. Well, I wish could, but it doesn't exist. Then I have found I can get it via

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

I run it and have this one

```
composer require laravel/passport
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/passport
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - artogrig/laravel-make-service[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.1] require illuminate/support ~5 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
        - Root composer.json requires artogrig/laravel-make-service ^1.0 -> satisfiable by artogrig/laravel-make-service[1.0.0, 1.0.1].
```

This is my comsposer.json:

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "artogrig/laravel-make-service": "^1.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^7.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^4.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",        
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do with. Could someone help me, please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The dependency `artogrig/laravel-make-service` only works with `Illuminate\Support` 5, for what this package does, create service classes and is unmaintained. I would simply just remove it and your dependencies would be fixed.

Comment: I removed it from Kernel.php. Now I have   

Problem 1
    - laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., 10.x-dev] require illuminate/auth ^8.2 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v10.1.0, 10.x-dev].

Comment: I will check later if those dependencies can work

Comment: I totally forgot about this, is this still relevant?

Comment: Yeah. I have not found solution (((